# Dynamic picklist Vs. All options with active/inactive selections

Tags: usability, design-patterns

In a tool that has filters that allow the User to drill down to the data that is most useful to them.

Would it be better to dynamically populate a Delivery Time pick list with only the available options to filter by? Meaning that the options are one to one with the available choices in data.

OR

Would it be better to show the pick list with every option that could be available and then go in a display active and inactive choices?

Additional context is that there are other filter controls, which are dynamically populated based on the available data with no erroneous data.

Comment: Are you sure nobody ever will reconsider to change another option, just to have his favorite delivery time available? Don't know what the other options are and what their relation to delivery time is. My design would change with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally recommend removing options from a filter if they are not going to be available. As a user, it might be frustrating to filter on an ideal delivery time, only to find that it is not available. Even more frustrating if they go through this multiple times.

Alternatively, you could let the user filter on any time, and then display a group of options as close to this as possible on either side. Think of how transport websites present options. If you search for a from / to destination at a certain time, they will present a small group of options as close to this time as possible, and buttons allowing you to view "earlier" or "later" options. For the below I selected a time of 10:30 for beginning my journey.

[image]